# Android maps refresh position of marker

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, refresh, google-maps-markers

I want to refresh the position of about 50-100 markers on a map every 5 seconds. It gets the position data from a web service, which all works fine. The problem is, I am getting huge lag on a Galaxy S5 when deleting all the markers and creating new ones.

Is there any other way to move markers? I don't think deleting them and recreating them is a good idea.

I saw other apps using the maps api and refreshing marker positions, but without any lag at all (for example FlightRadar24). How to solve that problem?

Update:
I am using the code from the answer below but it still recreates the marker every time. Does someone know why?

My ServiceData class:

```
public static class ServiceData {
    String ID;
    String title;
    String snippet;
    float hue;
    LatLng latlon;

    ServiceData(String id, String title, String snippet, float hue, LatLng latlon) {
        this.ID = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.snippet = snippet;
        this.hue = hue;
        this.latlon = latlon;
    }
}
```

Every time I update the markers I call `itemList.clear();` (Containing the ServiceData class) to clear it.

then I'm using 
`itemList.add(new ServiceData(id, line, snippet, hue, new LatLng(lat, lon));` to add the items to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you first add markers on the map, also add them to some `List` or `Map` (that will depend on data you are retrieving, and how you can identify markers), and then when you have to refresh marker location don't recreate markers, but set their positions to new values with `marker.setPosition(latlng);`

Code example for updating marker positions on the map:

```
public class ServiceData
{
    String id;
    LatLng latlng;
}

GoogleMap gmap;
public Map<String, Marker> markers = new HashMap<String, Marker>();
public List<ServiceData> list = new ArrayList<ServiceData>();

public void refreshMarkers()
{
    Map<String, Marker> updatedMarkers = new HashMap<String, Marker>();
    for (ServiceData data: list)
    {
        // if marker exists move its location, if not add new marker
        Marker marker = markers.get(data.id);
        if (marker == null)
        {
            marker = gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(data.latlng));
        }
        else 
        {
           marker.setPosition(data.latlng);
           markers.remove(data.id);
        }
        updatedMarkers.put(data.id, marker);
    }
    // all markers that are left in markers list need to be deleted from the map
    for (Marker marker : markers.values())
    {
        marker.remove();
    }

    markers = updatedMarkers;
}
```

Comment: almost each marker has its own color, and there are not always the same amount of markers to display, how would I solve that then?

Comment: But if the the markers are not in the same order anymore inside the data source? Also how would I compare them to see if they exist or not?

Comment: I get the data from a bus company. For example when the first entry in the list arrives at his destination, it will no longer appear in the list and entry 2 will become entry 1

Comment: I do have an id to identify each bus

Comment: thank you. Would I have to put this code in my `onMapReady()` method?

Comment: Also, how do I add data to ServiceData?

Comment: ServiceData is just dummy class I declared to show how to populate the map, that class should be replaced with real class you are using to retrieve data from web service.

Comment: `markers` and `list` declarations should be next to the `GoogleMap` declaration (in your map activity), and you should call `refreshMarkers()` each time you receive new data from your service and have to refresh data. Of course, you have to make sure that you don't call that before your map is initialized and ready.

Comment: Oh ok. So in the ServiceData class I would add the bus id and the coordinates?

Comment: So I just noticed your snippet deletes all the markers when I call `refreshMarkers()`. When I call it again it created them again.

Comment: Also most the times it just deletes the markers and recreates them without moving them

Comment: If above code is not working for you then the issue is not in that code but somewhere else, probably in code where you are recreating list of `ServiceData` that is used to refresh markers.

Comment: Your code in question looks fine. Try running code with debugger to see what is actually happening.